# INSERT INTO when using php and mysql with variables

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code. The error coming out is "Unknown column $idUsager in 'field list'". But that column is truly present.

php code:

```
$idUsager = $_POST['idUsager'];
$secMoment = $_POST['secMoment'];
$aire = $_POST['aire'];
$longueur = $_POST['longueur']; 
$idMateriau = $_POST['idMateriau']; 

//I connect to db and everything works properly here. Also, all variables contain numeric values only. No strings.

$query='INSERT INTO lesPoutres(idPoutre,idUsager,secMoment,aire,longueur,idMateriau)        
        VALUES(null,$idUsager,$secMoment,$aire,$longueur,$idMateriau)';

$result=mysql_query($query, $lien_bd);
  if (!$result) {
    print("<strong>Erreur lors du traitement de la requ&ecirc;te : </strong>" . mysql_error());

  exit();
  }
```

this is the mysql table:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idPoutre   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| idUsager   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| secMoment  | float unsigned   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| aire       | float unsigned   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| longueur   | float unsigned   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| idMateriau | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Truly present - Yes, in the query, but not in the database table. I highly suggest you start with a simple tutorial first. And learn about prepared statements, they allow you to use variables with your query. - http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

You need to use `"` when embedding variables into a string.

Replace

```
$query='INSERT INTO lesPoutres(idPoutre,idUsager,secMoment,aire,longueur,idMateriau)        
    VALUES(null,$idUsager,$secMoment,$aire,$longueur,$idMateriau)';
```

with

```
$query="INSERT INTO lesPoutres(idPoutre,idUsager,secMoment,aire,longueur,idMateriau)        
    VALUES(null,$idUsager,$secMoment,$aire,$longueur,$idMateriau)";
```

**Note**

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed. I suggest you to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

**Sql Injections**

Your script is vulnerable to sql injection. You should use `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
$idUsager = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idUsager']);
$secMoment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['secMoment']);
$aire = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aire']);
$longueur = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['longueur']); 
$idMateriau = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idMateriau']);
```

Comment: Well now I fell dumb. I've been on this for a long time and now knowing this I feel stupid. Thanks a LOT. "Internet hug".

Comment: @downvoter: mind to explain the down vote?

Comment: I'm interested t know why somebody has downvoted every answer too...

Comment: this code is widely open to SQL injection

Comment: @YourCommonSense, you mean that also applying the suggestion to use `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, could you please prove that statement sir? Possibly with a code example on how would `mysql_real_escape_string` be vulnerable to sql injections?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the input data in quotes :

Replace this

```
$query='INSERT INTO lesPoutres(idPoutre,idUsager,secMoment,aire,longueur,idMateriau)        
        VALUES(null,$idUsager,$secMoment,$aire,$longueur,$idMateriau)';
```

with this

```
$query="INSERT INTO lesPoutres(idPoutre,idUsager,secMoment,aire,longueur,idMateriau)        
        VALUES(null,'$idUsager','$secMoment','$aire','$longueur','$idMateriau')";
```

Also use mysqli or PDO. mysql_* function are depreciated .

Also escape the variables before inserting to prevent SQL injection

```
$idUsager = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idUsager']);
$secMoment = mysql_real_escape_string$_POST['secMoment']);
$aire = mysql_real_escape_string$_POST['aire']);
$longueur = mysql_real_escape_string$_POST['longueur']); 
$idMateriau = mysql_real_escape_string$_POST['idMateriau']);
```

More info on mysqli and PDO can be found here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @downvoter why is the downvote for ? What's the issue with this. Please explain

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

```
$idUsager = $_POST['idUsager'];
$secMoment = $_POST['secMoment'];
$aire = $_POST['aire'];
$longueur = $_POST['longueur']; 
$idMateriau = $_POST['idMateriau']; 

//I connect to db and everything works properly here. Also, all variables contain numeric values only. No strings.

$query="INSERT INTO lesPoutres VALUES (null,'$idUsager','$secMoment','$aire','$longueur','$idMateriau')";

$result=mysql_query($query, $lien_bd);
  if (!$result) {
    print("<strong>Erreur lors du traitement de la requ&ecirc;te : </strong>" . mysql_error());

  exit();
  }
```